# CSS Bootstrap - Align Navbar 'Icons' with edge of jumbotron

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align the selections in the navbar with the edges of the jumbotron, so that the rapidcodes logo aligns with the edge of the grey box in 'Newest Additions' and the 'login' button aligns with the right edge of the grey box.

See screenshot of current page:
[image]

Code:

```css
td {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: central;
 padding: 4px;
}

.products {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" >
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.rapidcodes.co.uk"><img src="http://www.rapidcodes.co.uk/style/logo.png" width="200" height="25" alt="Logo"/></a>
    </div>
    <div>
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="http://www.rapidcodes.co.uk">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Xbox<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Memberships</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gift Cards</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">PlayStation<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Memberships</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gift Cards</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">PC<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Time Cards</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You will need to include the code of the jumbo-tron as well.

Comment: @Manoj Kumar bootstrap default...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try packing your code inside the external div with the class of 'container'.

```html
<div class="container"><!--Pack your code inside the container-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" >
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.rapidcodes.co.uk"><img src="http://www.rapidcodes.co.uk/style/logo.png" width="200" height="25" alt="Logo"/></a>
    </div>
    <div>
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="http://www.rapidcodes.co.uk">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Xbox<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Memberships</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gift Cards</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">PlayStation<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Memberships</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gift Cards</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">PC<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Time Cards</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</div><!--end container-->
```

Comment: Thanks, worked brilliantly. Is there any way I can get the navbar background to extend the whole page still?

Comment: remove external container wrapper and replace your div container-fluid with container below navbar

Answer (score 1):

Your content probably has a container `.container`. Also wrap your navbar with this.

Comment: Thanks, worked brilliantly. Is there any way I can get the navbar background to extend the whole page still?

Comment: Yes of course. background layer > container > nav elements. Wrap only your nav elements with `.container` should be where your `.container-fluid` is

Comment: Thanks, figured something out using several containers!